# Is there any way to expose other port than defaults for azure web app?

Tags: azure, service, portal

I am trying to deploy a web service on an azure web app that opens port 53, is there any way to do that without creating a VM?

Answer (score 2):

> All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and
> Functions) run in a secure environment called a sandbox...
>
> ...The only way
> an application can be accessed via the internet is through the
> already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports. However,
> applications may create a socket which can listen for connections from
> within the sandbox.

source: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox